# Name for Juniper/Nginx/Caddy-like configuration format?

Tags: serialization, configuration-files

Is there a name for Juniper/Nginx/Caddy-like configuration format?

It looks like this: [juniper](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/routing-engine-single-initial-configuration.html#jd0e236) -- number 12, or [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/), or [caddy](https://github.com/caddyserver/examples/blob/master/nextcloud/Caddyfile):

```
simpleProperty value;
arrayProperty firstValue optionalValue optionalValue;

objectProperty requiredValue optionalValue {
   subSimpleNumberProperty 123;
   subArrayProperty "stringValue" "string value 2";
   subObjectProperty {
      nestedProperty value;
   }
}
```

Is there a name for this kind of format? (this is obviously not `json`/`cson`/`json5`, not `yaml`, not `ini`/`cfg`, also not `toml`)